# Class Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader\Proxy does not exist in vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I am getting below Error when we try to open **vitalticks.in**

> ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\Config\Initial\Reader\Proxy does not exist in /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #1 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...') #2 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...') #3 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...') #4 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...') #5 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\Framewo...', NULL, 'reader', 'Magento\Framewo...') #6 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\Framewo...', Array, Array) #7 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Framewo...', Array, Array) #8 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...') #9 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...') #10 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\Framewo...', NULL, 'initialConfig', 'Magento\Framewo...') #11 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\Framewo...', Array, Array) #12 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Framewo...', Array, Array) #13 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...') #14 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(196): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Framewo...') #15 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(172): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->parseArray(Array) #16 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, NULL, Array, 'processors', 'systemConfigPos...') #17 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('systemConfigPos...', Array, Array) #18 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('systemConfigPos...', Array, Array) #19 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('systemConfigPos...') #20 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('systemConfigPos...') #21 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\Framewo...', NULL, 'postProcessor', 'Magento\Config\...') #22 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\Config\...', Array, Array) #23 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments('Magento\Config\...', Array, Array) #24 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Config\...') #25 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(84): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\Config\...') #26 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Config/App/Config/Type/System/Reader/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->_getSubject() #27 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(371): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System\Reader\Proxy->read() #28 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/LockGuardedCacheLoader.php(79): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->readData() #29 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(261): Magento\Framework\Cache\LockGuardedCacheLoader->lockedLoadData('SYSTEM_CONFIG', Object(Closure), Object(Closure), Object(Closure)) #30 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(195): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->loadDefaultScopeData('default') #31 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-config/App/Config/Type/System.php(169): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->getWithParts('default/newreli...') #32 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(132): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/newreli...') #33 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(80): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/newreli...') #34 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(93): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('newrelicreporti...', 'default', NULL) #35 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Model/Config.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('newrelicreporti...') #36 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/module-new-relic-reporting/Plugin/HttpPlugin.php(49): Magento\NewRelicReporting\Model\Config->isNewRelicEnabled() #37 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\NewRelicReporting\Plugin\HttpPlugin->beforeCatchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(ReflectionException)) #38 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(ReflectionException)) #39 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('catchException', Array, Array) #40 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(267): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(ReflectionException)) #41 /home/vitaldotin/public_html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor)) #42 {main}

Answer (score 0):

1. chmod-R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
4. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
5. php bin/magento c:f